# ASP.NET MVC date string slash being converted to dash in Safari input fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, safari

I am outputting a DateTime to a string format of MM/dd/yyyy to an text input field. This works fine on all browsers except latest version of Safari (on Yosemite, if that matters). See examples below:

This code:

```
      <div><input type="text" value='@Model.Arrival.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")' /></div>
  <div><input type="text" value="@Html.Raw(Model.ArrivalDateString)" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" value="8/23/2015" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" value="08/23/2015" /></div>
```

Produces this:

[image: screenshot]

The test page I setup for this has absolutely nothing else running on it. It's just a bare bones HTML page with server side output from a view model. MVC 5 and .net framework 4.5.1

Viewing page source, it looks like this in Safari:

```
<input type="text" value="08-20-2015" />
```

On other browsers, it is this:

```
<input type="text" value="08/20/2015" />
```

- UPDATE: It looks like .NET is choosing a different culture / format for Safari browsers. A possible fix is to specify a format provider.

Comment: What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: The rendered HTML looks like this in Safari only: <div><input type="text" value="08-20-2015" /></div>. Every other browser it is value="08/20/2015"

Comment: Also note that the ArrivalDateString property is simply: get { return (Arrival.HasValue) ? Arrival.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by specifying a culture for the string format. ie.:

```
DateTime arrival = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo invariant = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateString = arrival.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", invariant);
```

en-US works as well. Still not sure why this happens. It looks like ASP.NET is doing something different based on the user agent. The request headers otherwise looks like same.

I would've figured this out earlier if I was able to get browserstack to work locally.